# KDE auto scaling screen after login with HiDPI monitor connected or not

Tags: kde, dpi

I have an internal 3840x2160 monitor, and an external 2560x1440 monitor.

I recently installed Manjaro with KDE 5.9. I have tried using `xrandr` with `scale 2x2`. It seems ok but is laggy.

I don't really need to use both screens. When I use Ubuntu with Unity, I can set different scale factor separately. When I use internal monitor only, it can be 200% scaled, when I plug in external monitor, the internal one black out, the external monitor lighted and is not scaled.

But in KDE, it cannot remember scale settings for two scenarios, for now I should login first, change scale settings, logout and back again. How can I get it working? Or take a step back, can I setup two custom login session config files to choose when logging in? What environment variables should I export or do something else?

I have noticed `QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS` and some other variables, but I have no idea how to manipulate with them.